# How can I deploy a node.js app to a private server after a successful Travis build/test?

Tags: node.js, github, travis-ci, continuous-deployment

This is the pipeline I have in mind for my node.js app:

write code at dev machine -> commit to github -> Travis builds and tests -> on success: deploy to private server

I'm looking for tool(s) to accomplish the last part.

For instance, some tool that would be notifed by Travis and would pull the code from the github to my private server (and deploy the app in that way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [travis-ci documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/custom/)

> You can easily deploy to your own server the way you would deploy from
>   your local machine by adding a custom after_success step.
>
> You may choose the Script provider instead, as it provides easier
>   flexibility with conditional deployment.

**FTP**

```
env:
  global:
    - "FTP_USER=user"
    - "FTP_PASSWORD=password"
after_success:
    "curl --ftp-create-dirs -T uploadfilename -u $FTP_USER:$FTP_PASSWORD ftp://sitename.com/directory/myfile"
```

> The env variables FTP_USER and FTP_PASSWORD can also be encrypted.
>
> See curl(1) for more details on how to use cURL as an FTP client.

**or Git**

```
after_success:
  - eval "$(ssh-agent -s)" #start the ssh agent
  - chmod 600 .travis/deploy_key.pem # this key should have push access
  - ssh-add .travis/deploy_key.pem
  - git remote add deploy DEPLOY_REPO_URI_GOES_HERE
  - git push deploy
```

> See “How can I encrypt files that include sensitive data?” if you
>   don’t want to commit the private key unencrypted to your repository.